# What is this propeller on the A330 MRRT refueling pod?

Tags: military, mid-air-refueling

[image]

Illustration taken from this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rREOX1WH-UA)

Earlier in the video, it can be seen moving:

[image]

Is it to provide mechanical power for the boom operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a ram air turbine which drives a fuel pump to provide pressure to transfer gas through the hose and drogue to the receiving aircraft.

Comment: Any source ? Why not use electric power ?

Comment: @Antzi from the linked duplicated question, "Pods operate with aircraft power or are self-powered by a Ram Air Turbine.". Also, the same solution is used on some EW pods

Comment: I believe it actually powers the hydraulic pump for the reel that runs the hose in and out.